Unable to push my ASP.NET Core 8 Web API to Azure; I am using clean architecture so all my services has been registered
My project builds successfully, but on publishing to Azure this error occurs:

Microsoft.WebTools.Shared.Exceptions.WebToolsException: Be sure that the Startup.cs for your application is calling AddSwaggerGen from within ConfigureServices in order to generate swagger file. Visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=2131205&CLCID=0x409 for more information.
at Microsoft.WebTools.Azure.Publish.ApiMApi.BaseApiMApiUpdater.EmitTerminatingError(String bucketName, String displayedErrorMessage, String loggedErrorMessage)  
at Microsoft.WebTools.Azure.Publish.ApiMApi.AppServiceApiMApiPublishHandler.AppServiceApiMApiUpdater.<GenerateSwaggerToBuildOutputDirAsync>d__12.MoveNext()  
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---  
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()  
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)  
at Microsoft.WebTools.Azure.Publish.ApiMApi.AppServiceApiMApiPublishHandler.AppServiceApiMApiUpdater.<RunUpdateAsync>d__10.MoveNext()  
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---  
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()  
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)  
at Microsoft.WebTools.Azure.Publish.ApiMApi.BaseApiMApiUpdater.<RunUpdateWithTelemetryAsync>d__9.MoveNext()  
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---  
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()  
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)  
at Microsoft.WebTools.Azure.Publish.ApiMApi.AppServiceApiMApiPublishHandler.<UpdateApiMApiAsync>d__14.MoveNext()  
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---  
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()  
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)  
at Microsoft.WebTools.Azure.Publish.NewFx.Profiles.BaseSwaggerPublishStep.<RunAsync>d__9.MoveNext()  
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---  
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()  
at Microsoft.Publish.Framework.Profiles.ProjectProfilesManager.<RunPublishStepsAsync>d__44.MoveNext()  


I am using .NET 8 and Visual Studio 2024 and I am registering the Swagger UI in my application.
here is my program.cs file
using Application.Abstractions;
using Infrastructure;
using Infrastructure.Context;
using Infrastructure.Extensions;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;
using WebAPI.Middleware;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddDbContext<BreaKonfusionContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("BreaKonfusionContext"))
);


builder.Services.AddApplication();
builder.Services.AddApplicationCQRS();
builder.Services.AddProblemDetails();
builder.Services.AddInfrastructure(builder.Configuration);
builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddTodoControllers();
builder.Services.AddSignalR();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Logging.AddAzureWebAppDiagnostics();

builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(option =>
{
    option.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "BreaKonfusion API", Version = "v1" });
    option.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
    {
        In = ParameterLocation.Header,
        Description = "Please enter a valid token",
        Name = "Authorization",
        Type = SecuritySchemeType.Http,
        BearerFormat = "JWT",
        Scheme = "Bearer"
    });
    option.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
    {
        {
            new OpenApiSecurityScheme
            {
                Reference = new OpenApiReference
                {
                    Type=ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                    Id="Bearer"
                }
            },
            new string[]{}
        }
    });
});
builder.Logging.ClearProviders(); 
builder.Logging.AddConsole(); 
builder.Logging.AddDebug();
builder.Services.AddScoped<ExceptionHandlingMiddleware>();



var app = builder.Build();
app.UseRouting();


// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Breakonfusion API V1");
});
app.UseCors(CorsExtensions.MyAllowSpecificOrigins);
// await app.Services.InitializeDbAsync();

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseMiddleware<ExceptionHandlingMiddleware>();
app.UseCurrentUser();
app.MapTodoHubs();
app.MapControllers();


app.Run();


The error says you need to do something specific. You didn't show your code. Please provide a [mcve].

i have added my program.cs file now

How you are deploying your app?

I am using visual studio code and I’m publishing it to an app service running windows.

@Awwal15 Try to use this code app.UseSwagger(); app.UseSwaggerUI(x => {     x.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Web API V1"); if(app.Environment.IsDevelopment())     x.RoutePrefix = "swagger"; // For localhost else     x.RoutePrefix = string.Empty; //  For azure } ); in your program.cs file.

@AsleshaKantamsetti i tried this it is still not working same error message

What exactly do you mean by publishing to Azure? The top of the stack trace Microsoft.WebTools.Azure.Publish.ApiMApi.BaseApiMApiUpdater.EmitTerminatingError implies that there is API Management involved somewhere, which is not what I would typically think of when discussing publishing a web app - that would be an App Service publish, which has no connection to APIM (unless there is some code reuse I am not aware of in the platform)

Missed the previous comment specifying app service running windows

Please try to upgrade your vscode to latest version. And install Azure Resources , Azure App Service extensions.
If you have sign in the azure account, please sign out and sign in again.
If the issue still occurs, we can deploy the project via azure cli. If we can deploy it successfully via command, then we can confirm there is no-permission issue with your account.
Here is the detailed steps.
PS C:\Users\Jason\source\repos\ReactApp4\WebApplication1> dotnet publish -c Release -o ./publish 
PS C:\Users\Jason\source\repos\ReactApp4\WebApplication1> Compress-Archive -Path "C:\Users\Jason\source\repos\ReactApp4\WebApplication1\publish\*" -DestinationPath "C:\Users\Jason\source\repos\ReactApp4\WebApplication1\publish.zip" 
PS C:\Users\Jason\source\repos\ReactApp4\WebApplication1> az webapp deploy --resource-group jasonp2 --name jasontestwebapp --src-path "C:\Users\Jason\source\repos\ReactApp4\WebApplication1\publish.zip" --type zip


If we can deployed successfully, then we can also deploy this way, not sure if it's caused by extensions.

i swtiched to a vps everything seems to work fine form there
